# Socket.io and Express ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: node.js, express, https, socket.io, github-pages

My code is hosted on the GitHub Pages. I'm trying to connect client to my computer's Node.JS server by IP, but connection says an error `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`.

That's my server code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('https').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.set('host', process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0');

server.listen(app.get('port'), app.get('host'), () => {
  console.log("Express server listening IP: " + app.get('host'));
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('sayHi', data => {
        console.log(data.message);
    });
});
```

And this is client side:

```
const socket = io.connect('https://myPublicIP:8080');
socket.emit('sayHi', { message: 'Hello world' });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error happen because you using HTTPS for running SocketIO Server.

So we have two way for resolve this issue:

1. Change `require('https')` to `require('http')`
2. Import your Certificate SSL files when createServer following this example source code

   ```
   const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, 'utf8')
   const certificate = fs.readFileSync(process.env.CERTIFICATE, 'utf8')
   const credentials = {
       key: privateKey, 
       cert: certificate, 
       passphrase: process.env.PASSPHRASE
   }
   var server = require('https').createServer(credentials, app);
   ```

Hope this can help you!

Comment: If I'll use self-signed cert will it ok?

Comment: @BXD: Yes you can by configure at your Client `var socket = io.connect('//yourhost:8080', {secure: true, rejectUnauthorized: false})`

Comment: try giving credentials like this

const credentials = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/server.crt'),
    cacert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/ca.crt')
}

Comment: Excellent, thanks for this! the fs.readFileSync did the trick